# How to subset datetime stamps to randomly keep only one value per day in R?

Tags: r, datetime, duplicates, subset

I am a GIS analyst and using R for a project. I am a bit rusty with R code. I have data in csv format from radio collared foxes with datetime stamps and GPS locations. However, throughout our study the time interval changed so some of the dates have 3 records per day and some have only one. For example:

```
[1] 2014-12-24 03:00:00 
[2] 2014-12-24 12:00:00
[3] 2014-12-24 22:00:00.
```

There are duplicate datetimes as well that I need to thin, but they have different GPS locations:

```
[55] 2015-11-03 12:00:00
[56] 2015-11-03 12:00:00.
```

Ultimately I need just one record per day and I would like it to randomly choose which one is deleted so that I end up with a mix of time values. For example:

```
[1] 2014-12-24 12:00:00
[2] 2014-12-25 22:00:00.
```

I tried the `!duplicate` function with the date only in a separate column but the problem is it only returns the first value so all the times would be at 3:00 am. example code:

```
oneaday6730 <- xFox6730[!duplicated(xFox6730$Date), drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: What's the exact structure of your data? The answer really depends on that. Use `dput(yourData)`

Comment: Scramble the order of your data, de-duplicate it, then re-order the rows that remain.

Comment: @GGamba my data is from CSV and these are my column headings:Names = c("RecordID", "DateTime", "Zone", 
    "Northing", "Easting", "Type", "DenID", "Gender", "Site", 
    "Season", "Time", "Date", "TTF", "Altitude", "Maxsnr", "Hdop", 
    "Vdop", "Satt", "Fix", "V1", "T1", "X22").

Comment: @Gregor- the values are dates with time included so I am not sure how I can change the order of them without changing them from datetime format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `dplyr`, assuming `mydf` is your data:

```
mydf %>%
    group_by(Date) %>%
    sample_n(1) -> result
```

Note that I'm making some assumptions on the structure of your data, in particular that the `Date` column contains the date you want to sample on.

Comment: Thank you @GGamba. the %>% gave an error, but this code worked for me ("xFox6730" is my dataframe): install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
bydate<- group_by(xFox6730,Date) 
oneadaytest<-sample_n(bydate,1)